# draw arbitrary domain with different colors on the domain boundary

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I want to draw an arbitrary domain in tikz with different colors on the boundary. I have managed to draw an arbitrary domain but I am not able to color the boundary properly.

here's a picture of how I want it to look like (shape need not be exact), especially the coloring of the boundary in the domain

[image]

here's a MWE of what I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} [line width=1.2, scale=2 ]

\def\x{1} ;
\def \y{4};


%%%% Domain in reference configuration
\draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(1.0,.1)(1.75,0.05)(2.5,.5)(2.9,1.5)(2.8,2.8)(2.0, 2.9)(1.0,2.6)(0.3, 1.3)(0.5,0.5)} node at (2.6,2.6)[ scale=1] {$\mathcal{B}$};


\draw [blue, line width=2mm, opacity=0.5] plot [smooth ] coordinates {(2.9,1.5)(2.8,2.8)(2.0, 2.9)(1.0,2.6)};

\draw[red, line width=2mm, opacity=0.5] plot [smooth ] coordinates {(1.75,0.05)(2.5,.5)(2.9,1.5)};

\draw [blue, line width=2mm, opacity=0.5]plot [smooth] coordinates {(0.5,0.5)(1.0,.1)(1.75,0.05)};

\draw [red, line width=2mm, opacity=0.5]plot [smooth] coordinates {(1.0,2.6)(0.3, 1.3)(0.5,0.5)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

On compiling, it looks like below:

[image]

The colors along the boundary don't look smooth. In fact I find it completely inelegant.

Is there a way to get it like it is in the first picture ?

Comment: Draw the curve twice and clip properly.

Comment: i some how understand that I need to draw the curve multiple times and color them accordingly,  but I don't know about clip. Do you mind posting a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With clip. (Conceptually the same as [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12033/121799).)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} [line width=1.2, scale=2 ]
%%%% Domain in reference configuration
\draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(1.0,.1)(1.75,0.05)(2.5,.5)(2.9,1.5)(2.8,2.8)(2.0, 2.9)(1.0,2.6)(0.3, 1.3)(0.5,0.5)} node at (2.6,2.6)[ scale=1] {$\mathcal{B}$};
\begin{scope}
\clip plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(2.9,1.5)(1.0,2.6)(0.3, 1.3)(2.5,.5)};
\draw[blue, line width=2mm, opacity=0.5] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(1.0,.1)(1.75,0.05)(2.5,.5)(2.9,1.5)(2.8,2.8)(2.0, 2.9)(1.0,2.6)(0.3, 1.3)(0.5,0.5)};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(2.9,1.5)(1.0,2.6)(0.3, 1.3)(2.5,.5)}
(current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\draw[red, line width=2mm, opacity=0.5] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(1.0,.1)(1.75,0.05)(2.5,.5)(2.9,1.5)(2.8,2.8)(2.0, 2.9)(1.0,2.6)(0.3, 1.3)(0.5,0.5)};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]